# Best way to store raw data for graph data update

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly.js

I want to update my plotly.js graph every time user clicks and select specific value from dropdown menu.

Just want to know best practice to store data, so I can query based upon user selection.

So it's good to call API every time for selection OR get data in JavaScript as first call when page loads and use it again and again by filtering it?

I'm just wondering if we load all raw data in 1 call and if it's too big for user's browser.

Please suggest best practice to update graphs

PS : I'm using Flask as framework and generating graphs with plotly.js

Comment: How many and what kind of data have you to load?

Comment: @Frighi It's just beginning for me, honestly I don't know bigger it went, so just asking for help here to take care of such thing in earlier stage of development